# Why is the Curl of a non-uniform electric field still 0?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

So I intuitively think about taking the curl as, taking a step perpendicular to the direction the vector (describing a field at a point in space) is pointing in and seeing how the field changes. If the magnitude changes then the curl is non-zero.

But $\nabla \times E = 0$ is true for all electrostatic charge configurations. I can think of a way to have a nonuniform electric field where if you take a perpendicular step, then the magnitude of the field changes. But of course, that cannot be true, so what is the explanation here.

Comment: I am confused by a question. Sure, you can imagine an electric field with a non-zero curl. That doesn't mean that such an electric field could be generated by a static charge configuration.

Comment: your understanding of the curl is wrong

Comment: @d_b I think this is the correct answer. I believe I am imagining fields that might not be generated by a static charge configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Curl is much better thought of as describing how that a field *locally fails to conserve energy.* It is a differential operator, so what it does, in effect, is measure some kind of behavior of the field when viewed "under infinite magnification" around a single, particular point.

In particular, a nonzero curl of a vector field at a point means taking a(n ideally) tiny loop around that point will extract work, were the field to be viewed as a force field (which, in this case, it is). The more curl there is there, the more work - suitably adjusted for the tininess of the loop - can be pulled out. Hence why a static system of charges cannot produce a nonvanishing curl in the electric field, because that would imply that you could violate conservation of energy in an absolute sense. You need a dynamic system of charges, which thus contains kinetic energy that can be converted by that extraction process.

Since you are talking a tiny loop, simply taking one step alone is not enough to reveal the curl behavior of the field. You need to imagine taking a whole, little tiny loop, and imagine the force from the field alternately tugging on you in different directions as you do - and a curl of zero means that, for every bit of time in walking on the loop where you were walking "with" the pull of the field, there was enough time walking "against" the pull of the field to result in a total net zero combination of assistance gained and work done in resistance.

That is, the intuition you are using is not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another intuitive picture for the curl: The curl / rotation of the vector field at a point $\vec{x}$ is proportional to the torque applied on a theoretical tiny spherical probe, on which surface the vector field applies a force.

In the context of Electrostatics, w.l.o.g let the electric field $\vec{E}$ have non-vanishing curl at the origin $\nabla \times \vec{E} \neq 0$. Imagine now  a tiny probe sphere of radius $r$ (as a rigid body), that has a constant surface charge density of $\sigma^+$. Torque is defined as $\vec{\tau}= \vec{r}\times \vec{F}$, thus the entire torque reads with $\vec{F} = q \vec{E}$ and $dq = \sigma^+ dA$
\begin{equation}
\vec{T} = \sigma^+ \int_{\partial V}\vec{r}\times \vec{E} \;dA = \sigma^+ r \int_V \nabla \times \vec{E} \; dV \approx (\sigma^+ r V) \cdot \nabla \times \vec{E} 
\end{equation}
where the integral equality holds according to the general Stokes theorem and the approximation is justified by arguing that over the "tiny" Volume $V$, the curl of $\vec{E}$ only changes negligibly.

Now given this, you can convince yourself pictorially that there are non-uniform electric fields with vanishing curl by checking that they do not exert any torque on an imagined, charged probe sphere, regardless of where it is placed.

As a side note: of course, if there was a position with $\nabla \times \vec{E}\neq 0$ and one placed such a probe there, because of the torque it would start rotating. The resulting current $\vec{j}$ on the surface would cause building up a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ and the resulting electric field $\vec{E} = -\nabla \Phi - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{A}$ would put up a torque on other charges with respect to the position of the probe.